# Apache proxy redirect URLs with specific string

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, httpd, mod-proxy, proxypass

I have a server which runs 2 applications. I am using a public IP address and I want to parse the url in a way if a specific text occurs the call is redirect to a specific port. In my case I want that if the url contains:

- /myapp1/a1 -> port 82
- /myapp2/a2 -> port 81

examples:
Supposing my public ip is p.u.b.l, my private ip is p.r.i.v, the following URLs should be resolved by the server in this way:

http://p.u.b.l./myapp1/a1/something -> http://p.r.i.v.:82/myapp1/a1/something
http://p.u.b.l./myapp2/a2/something -> http://p.r.i.v.:81/myapp2/a2/something

I am trying to configure Apache in a way to provide reverse proxy. Following my configuration in site-availables, also added in site-enabled:

```
ServerName p.r.i.v

ProxyPassMatch "/myapp1/a1(.*)$" "http://p.r.i.v:82/myapp1/a1/$1"
ProxyPassReverse "/myapp1/a1(.*)$" "http://p.r.i.v:82/myapp1/a1/$1"

ProxyPassMatch "/myapp2/a2(.*)$" "http://p.r.i.v:81/myapp2/a2/$1"
ProxyPassReverse "/myapp2/a2(.*)$" "http://p.r.i.v:81/myapp2/a2/$1"
```

But the redirect is not working. What am I missing? Please consider the direct access to the private resource works, meaning *http://p.r.i.v:81/myapp2/a2/something*, but the *http://p.u.b.l/myapp2/a2/something* is not resolved

Any help is appreciated
Thanks
Simone

Comment: I think you don't need regex matching and can do with a "simple" ProxyPass: 

`ProxyPassMatch "/myapp1/a1/" "http://p.r.i.v:82/myapp1/a1/"`  and 
`ProxyPassReverse "/myapp1/a1/" "http://p.r.i.v:82/myapp1/a1/"` and don't forget to balance in both the URL and target the trailing `/` when you add/omit those

Comment: Hi @HBruijn, I've used the ProxyPass as suggested but I received no improvement. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is resolved. In the proxied url there was an encoded char, which needed a proper definition. In this case, I added `AllowEncodedSlashes On` and `nocanon` next to the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse rules.

Thanks
Simone